# When exactly to use keyword throws in method signature?

Tags: java, exception

I am reading Java Complete Reference by Helbert Schildt where he shows this example using exceptions.

```
class ThrowDemo {
       static void demoproc() {
         try {
           throw new NullPointerException("demo");
         } catch(NullPointerException e) {
           System.out.println("Caught inside demoproc.");
           throw e; // rethrow the exception
         }
       }
       public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {
           demoproc();
         } catch(NullPointerException e) {
           System.out.println("Recaught: " + e);
         }
       } 
}
```

Why does not method `demoproc()` have keyword `throws` in it's signature when it can potentially throw exception in the catch clause?

Comment: Because NullPointerException is not a checked exception

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is [un-checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). You only need delcare the exception in method signature when it is checked exception.